# algorithm - determine if there are diagonals of a certain size with the same value in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, math, matrix

I can't figure out how to handle the following situation: I have a `9*9` matrix, and a given element of the matrix. I want to find out if the element is part of a diagonal (of a given size) formed by elements with the same value.

For example: if I have the element at `[7][5]`, its associated value `1`, and the values of the elements situated at `[8][4]`,`[6][6]`,`[5][7]`,`[4][8]` have also the value `1`, than it means that `[7][5]` is part of a diagonal that contains 5 elements.

I need this algorithm to implement a Lines game in Java. Could you please help me out with the correct approach to this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, lets observe that it can be two diagonals. 
Easiest solution is expanding in four possible directions until value
is different or we hit the border of matrix. If we finish on the border
in both endpoints that means that it belongs to diagonal.
Pseudocode for this could as follows

```
boolean expands(x, y, dir_x, dir_y, matrix):
  x1 = x
  y1 = y
  while positionInBorder(x1, y1):
    if matrix[x][y] != matrix[x1][y1]:
      return false
    x1 += dir_x
    y1 += dir_y      
  return true

boolean inDiagonal(x, y, matrix):
   return (expands(x, y, -1, -1, matrix) and expands(x, y, +1, +1, matrix)) or
          (expands(x, y, +1, -1, matrix) and expands(x, y, -1, +1, matrix))
```

In case you needed to calculate all such points, which is quite
natural keeping in mind game context, you could use more efficient algorithm.
You check all possible diagonals and if they have the same value,
set flag for all elements in it:

```
isInDiagonal[n][n] = False for all i, j.
for start_position in top_row and left_column of matrix:
   go down right while same value:
      if reached bondary:
        pass again and set isInDiagonal[x][y] for each item in diagonal
for start_position in top_row and right_column of matrix:
   go down left while same value:
      if reached bondary:
        pass again and set isInDiagonal[x][y] for each item in diagonal

return isInDiagonal
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. (In the second chunk of code you mean left_column and right_column, right?)

Answer (score 1):

If you are at position [x][y] (in your example x=7, y=5), then you want to inspect the four directions until they stop having the value at [x][y]. Then take the maximums.

```
int t[][]; //that's the matrix
int[] dx = new int[] { 1, -1, 1, -1 };
int[] dy = new int[] { -1, 1, 1, -1 };

static boolean checkBoundaries(int x, int y) {
    return x >= 0 && x <= t.length && y >= 0 && y <= t[0].length
}

static int CountInDirection (int x, int y, int dir){
    int ret = 0;
    int val = t[x][y];
    x+=dx[dir];
    y+=dy[dir];
    while(chechBoundaries(x,y) && t[x][y] == val)
        ++ret;

    return ret;
}

static void main(String[] args){
    int diag1 = CountInDirection (7,5,0) + CountInDirection (7,5,1);
    int diag2 = CountInDirection (7,5,2) + CountInDirection (7,5,3);
    System.out.println("Max diag is: " + Math.max(diag1, diag2));
}
```